# How to retrieve ajax url content return values

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

i'm write some of code for send data from one page to another page through the ajax URL data string values are send and another page also execute.

But retrieve the page values to previous page not showing null will show

First Page Code look like this :
and the script will be working fine but whenever we send data through url page join.php i will get some information to main page and how to i get that information for the front page

```
 <script>
       function myFunction() {
    var size = document.getElementById("size").value;
    var numpols = document.getElementById("numpols").value;
    var ppdistance = document.getElementById("ppdistance").value;

    // AJAX code to submit form.
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "join.php",
     dataType:"html",
      data: data,
     success: function(data){
        if(!data){   
         console.log(data);
            }
      }
    });
    }
    return false;
    }



    </script>



    Join.php Page look like this 

    <?php

    extract($_POST);
    $feet1=22;
    $feet2=27;

    $sql="select Add_Price,sub_category from consumerprice where Add_Size='$size'";
                       $res=$conn->query($sql);

                          while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {

                                 $price=$row['Add_Price'];
                                 $category = $row['sub_category'];

                                 $numpols*$ppdistance*$numfencinglineperpole;
                                 $multi=(($numpols*$ppdistance*$numfencinglineperpole)/$feet1);   
                                 //echo $multi=round($multi);
                                  echo  $subcar;
                                  echo  $totlamulti="Quantity=  $multi Kgs";
                                  echo  $totPrice = "Total Price = " .$multi * $price;
                                  $i++; }

    }

    ?>

i will display the return values is 

      echo  $subcar;
      echo  $totlamulti="Quantity=  $multi Kgs";
      echo  $totPrice = "Total Price = " .$multi * $price;

These three values can i return the first page
```

i will check the dataString, data, JSON also checking out put will not display return empty values.

Comment: your `myFunction` appears to be badly formed in the code you posted above. Do you get errors?

Comment: AJAX is, by definition, asynchronous and will not, as such, return a value because of that asynchronous nature. You should use the ajax callback function to perform whatever tasks need to be done with the results from the database

Comment: where is `data` defined in or before `myFunction`?

Comment: your sql is vulnerable to `SQL Injection` - use `prepared statements` rather than embedding user supplied data directly in the sql query

Comment: can u please explain i am not able to understand

Comment: explain which comment?

Comment: i will send the dataString to join.php page and execute the code and values null display in the  first page and join.php page i will echo three value those three values i will display in the firstpage .

Comment: can u explain to how to write a code i am new for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not really use `jQuery` at all so excuse the dodgy jQuery coding - perhaps this might assist in your efforts. You will need to complete various bits for yourself - the database work for example.

```
<?php
    error_reporting( E_ALL );
    ini_set( 'display_errors', 1 );

    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){
        ob_clean();

        $errors=array();
        $args=array(
            'size'          =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT,
            'numpols'       =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT,
            'ppdistance'    =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT
        );

        foreach( array_keys( $args ) as $field ){
            if( !isset( $_POST[ $field ] ) ) $errors[]=sprintf( 'The field "%s" is not set', $field );
        }

        foreach( $_POST as $field => $value ){
            if( !in_array( $field, array_keys( $args ) ) )$errors[]=sprintf( 'Unknown field "%s"', $field );
        }

        if( empty( $errors ) ){

            $_POST=filter_input_array( INPUT_POST, $args );
            extract( $_POST );

            $feet1=22;
            $feet2=27;
            $subcar='banana';   # what? where? when?

            /* 
                This is where you connect to your database 
                and run whatever queries you want.

                        .^. .  _    
                        /: ||`\/ \~  ,       
                      , [   &    / \ y'   
                     {v':   `\   / `&~-,  
                    'y. '    |`   .  ' /   
                     \   '  .       , y   
                     v .        '     v   
                     V  .~.      .~.  V   
                     : (  0)    (  0) :   
                      i `'`      `'` j     
                       i     __    ,j     
                        `%`~....~'&         
                     <~o' /  \/` \-s,        
                      o.~'.  )(  r  .o ,.  
                     o',  %``\/``& : 'bF  
                    d', ,ri.~~-~.ri , +h  
                    `oso' d`~..~`b 'sos`  
                         d`+ II +`b              
                         i_:_yi_;_y 


            */
            /*

            $dbhost =   'localhost';
            $dbuser =   'I-am-Groot'; 
            $dbpwd  =   'groot'; 
            $dbname =   'groot';

            mysqli_report( MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT );
            $db = new mysqli( $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpwd, $dbname );

            $sql='select `Add_Price`, `sub_category` from `consumerprice` where `Add_Size`=?';
            $stmt=$db->prepare( $sql );
            $stmt->bind_param( 's', $size );
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->store_result();
            $stmt->bind_result($price,$category);

            while( $stmt->fetch() ){
                # you can access the database results here as $price and $category
            }

            */

            # do your calculations...

            /*
            $multi=( ( $numpols * $ppdistance * $numfencinglineperpole ) / $feet1 );

            echo  $subcar;
            echo  $totlamulti="Quantity=  $multi Kgs";
            echo  $totPrice = "Total Price = " .$multi * $price;
            */



            # dummy output
            echo '
                subcar: X
                Total: Quantity=$multiKgs
                Total Price=$multi*$price;
            ';


        }


        exit();
    }


?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title></title>
        <script src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js'></script>
        <script>
            $( document ).on( 'ready', ( e )=>{

                const myFunction=function(e){

                    let data={
                        size:$('[name="size"]').val(),
                        numpols:$('[name="numpols"]').val(),
                        ppdistance:$('[name="ppdistance"]').val()
                    }

                    $.ajax({
                        type:"POST",
                        url: location.href, //"join.php"
                        dataType:"html",
                        data: data,
                        success: function(response){
                            document.querySelector( 'output' ).innerHTML=response;
                        },
                        error: function(error){
                            alert( error )
                        }
                    });
                };
                document.querySelector( 'form > [ type="button" ]' ).addEventListener('click', myFunction );
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method='post'>
            <label>Size<input type='number' name='size' /></label>
            <label>Numpols<input type='number' name='numpols' /></label>
            <label>PPDistance<input type='number' name='ppdistance' /></label>
            <input type='button' value='Submit' />
        </form>
        <output></output>
    </body>
</html>
```